# I always come in groups

Tags: riddle

> I always come in groups.
>   
> I like to hang around.
>   
> My spirit gives you pleasure,
>   
> But only when it's downed.

What am I?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are:

> Grapes

I always come in groups.

> Grapes come in bunches.

I like to hang around.

> Grapes hang off vines.

My spirit gives you pleasure,

> Grapes are used to make wine, which people like to drink.

But only when it's downed.

> Down the mouth.

Comment: Also [spirit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distilled_beverage)

Comment: Correct!  Good job.

Comment: @Narmer - I admit, I took a little creative license with that line.  Though, if you consider Hotel California: So I called up the Captain, "Please bring me my wine." He said, "We haven't had that spirit here since nineteen sixty nine."

Comment: @Cubicon actually, in the linked wiki, the very first sentence is _A distilled beverage, **spirit**, liquor, or hard liquor is an alcoholic beverage produced by distillation of a mixture produced from alcoholic fermentation, **such as wine**._

Comment: @Narmer - Ah, thank you.  Initially, I thought it was a counterexample.  Eagles still rock, though.

Comment: @Cubicon there's absolutely no doubt :-)

Answer (score 2):

It is

> water

It Comes in Group

> You mesure it in ml of liter you can not count it alone.

I like Hang around

> Water always flows in River or sea.

My spirit Gives you pleasure

> Yes it always gives pleasure when we drink it or we swim in it.

But only when it's downed.

> because when it's up we call it flood and it is harmful.

Answer (score 1):

It is

> Rain

I always come in groups.

> of course, its in groups

I like to hang around.

> Rain hang activities when fall suddenly.

My spirit gives you pleasure,

> its pleasure to feel rain

But only when it's downed.

> its all only when its downed to earth.